# How to correctly use a Lua-XML parser (lua expat / LuaXml)

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, lua, luaxml

I have C++ code in Visual Studio that I execute and this does eventually execute my `.lua` files with my Lua code.
My goal is to make an XML file available for Lua.
After some research I now know that I will need to use a parser for that.

Two good parsers seem to be:

- [lua expat](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/luaexpat/)
- [LuaXML](http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/)

The problem is, I don't know how to use these. Yes, it sounds simple but I'm quite new to this whole thing and did not understand the description of these parsers. So my questions are these:

1. How can I use/install the parser(s), to be more precise, which files must be put where?
2. What exactly do I have to do after that to make an XML file available for Lua?
3. Will the parsed data be available in a different file or directly inside my Lua code?

Answer (score 1):

I use LuaXML for my requirements, because it was the first result on search, and it had some very good examples documented on [lua-users.org](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml).

You can also look at lua eXpat's examples on their [project website](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/luaexpat/examples.html).

## Installation

If you're a Windows owner, you can take a look at [lua For Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/). It has many other 'batteries' as they call it. :)

For Linux, the installation instructions are pretty well documented on their respective websites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did indeed see all these examples. But I still can t figure out what to do(it s too abstract, since I m new in this sphere).
How do you use LuaXML?Do you start the .exe file(that comes with the download) and type smth?Do you put certain files anywhere?
Sorry for asking so much in detail but I just don t know otherwise.
ps. I use windows too.

Comment: meanwhile I tried it with lua for windows(see comment above) but I m still lost in questions.So any help is still very appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Both LuaXML and LuaExpat consist of a C library and a Lua glue file.

The C file can be compiled into a DLL on Windows, and the DLL must be put somewhere in the path given by `package.cpath`. A possible alternative, if you compile Lua from source in Visual Studio, is to compile `LuaXML_lib.c` (assuming LuaXML) together with Lua files and add `luaopen_LuaXML_lib` to the module list found in `linit.c`.

The Lua library file `LuaXml.lua` must be placed in one of the directory listed in `package.path`.

If you don't know the paths on your system, try running :

```
print("C path:", package.cpath)
print("Lua path:", package.path)
```

Comment: Alright, I will try this at my work pc tomorrow morning.
Just another question ahead:(1) Where do I actually execute/ type orders?I mean.. In my lua console? Or in this exe file that comes with the download?(2) Will LuaXML generate a new file(for lua usage) that contains the former xml data or where exactly can I access this data?

Comment: Run these lines in your Lua console. LuaXML does not create file when it parses an XML file, instead it returns an _object_ (actually a table) representing the XML content stored in memory.

Comment: I tried it via visual studios and it did not work. When I enter the code in the console, it says that a file is not found.
I downloaded lua for windows(so no compiling from vs) and used the normal console window. No error shows up when I type in the lines.
My problem is now, what exactly do I have to type in there?If I follow the example nothing happens...
Man I feel so lost here..I hope you can help me out..